# Let ec2 which is made cdk exec start script like Dockerfile

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cdk

I made `ec2` instance with this code.

```
const ec2Instance = new ec2.Instance(this, "Instance", {
  vpc,
  instanceType: ec2.InstanceType.of(
    ec2.InstanceClass.T2,
    ec2.InstanceSize.MICRO
  ),
  machineImage: new ec2.AmazonLinuxImage({
    generation: ec2.AmazonLinuxGeneration.AMAZON_LINUX_2,
    cpuType: ec2.AmazonLinuxCpuType.X86_64,
  }),
  securityGroup: securityGroup,
  keyName: "default_aws"
});
```

`ec2` is correctly made but ,there is no application in int ( That's of course)

Normally, after starting the `ec2` I log-in and do some commands such as

```
sudo yum update 
sudo yum install wget
sudo yum install emacs
```

I want to exec these command as default when ec 2 is built.

For Docker image I can write the command in `Dockerfile`

Is there any equivalent things to do?

1. I checked the ec2 aws UI and found some images and template, is it relevant?

2)Or Can I have something like start scripts in `cdk`??

I guess It might be common requirement, though, I can't find good information yet.

My final goal is making mysql installed ec2 with cdk, but at first I need to understand the basic idea of `ec2` start script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put those commands in a file and read that file in the script like so:

```
const userDataScript = readFileSync('./lib/user-data.sh', 'utf8');
 // add user data to the EC2 instance
 ec2Instance.addUserData(userDataScript);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I understood user data works well.